# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am using objects in php. I have an object to connect to database server $con object and $opt (operation) object to send query to database server, till now there is no problem, the problem is that I defined the $con object as static and I defined it in $opt object as it shows in below code

```
  class operations{

   public static $con = null;
   public function __construct($tableName = null){

     // Creating  an object of connection 
     self::$con = new config();
     self::$con = self::$con->getConnection();
   }

  }
```

So when I want to call the $con object there is no problem

```
mysql_query($query,$opt::$con) or die (mysql_error());
```

but on server it appears with this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

Comment: $opt is an object of class operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope resolution is unexpected, that means that you use it in a bad context.
When do you use "::"? After `self` `static`, classname or a string representing the name of a class :

```
 static::PropertyOrMethod;
 self::PropertyOrMethod;
 CLassName::PropertyOrMethod
 $string = "className";
 $string::PropertyOrMethod
```

Instead of that, you use it over ans instance of your class and php does not like it.
You should use
    mysql_query($query,operations::$con) or die (mysql_error());

Comment: thanks man its working , you are right the static objects dont need the object to reach it , thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM is Hebrew, and it refers to PHP’s scope resolution operator (“::”). If you get this message, it means PHP sees a class name and expects you to access it with the scope resolution operator.

**update:**

After seeing the edit to you code you made a mistake in the call. The right syntax is:

```
mysql_query( $query, operations::$con ) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: He **is** using the :: operator :): `$opt::$con`

Comment: but I used it as you see mysql_query($query,$opt::$con) or die (mysql_error());